# Swift return associated enum value or nil in one line

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Case statements are not always intuitive, especially outside of switch statements.

Is it possible to return the associated value of an enum case *only* if that case matches, otherwise nil, in one line. Here's the code:

```
struct Something<B> {
    enum Base {
        case common(B)
        case extended([B])
    }

    let base:Base

    var common:B? {
        switch base {
        case .common(let common) :
            return common
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

See how `common` has a lot of boilerplate just to return the associated value of common if it exists. I would hope for syntax similar to this (or even simpler):

```
var common:B? {
    return case base as .common(let common)
}
```

(currently using Swift 4)

Comment: Or something like this: `return (case .common(let common) = base)` which is still a bit verbose for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit shorter

```
var common:B? {
    if case let .common(common) = base { return common }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's as good as it gets. Maybe I'll file an issue with the Swift team.

Comment: @DavidJames - How much shorter would be clear and readable (like the elegance of that triple keyword run `if case let`)? Maybe something like `return case .common(common) ? common : nil` would suit you? It is almost Swift, and has a C-esque brevity. However Swift doesn't support pattern matching in the ternary operator (orthogonality be damned?), or omitting `let` (so you know its not `var`?). Maybe you should just accept the glory of the triple keyword? ;-)